# Error Code: 1449 The user specified as a definer (''bs@'%') does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу делат апдейт на таблице видает такую ошибку

Error Code: 1449 The user specified as a definer (''bs@'%') does not exist

```
UPDATE case_changes SET status_id = 2 WHERE status_id in (22,110,111)
```

Comment: Похоже на ошибку подключения.

Comment: @msi А какой при ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИИ может быть DEFINER?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что дело не в запросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну и кто виноват, что юзера удалили? итог - сервер не может делегировать права (не от кого). Конечно, проблему вызывает не сам запрос, а некая созданная от имени этой учётной записи процедура, выполняемая при выполнении этого запроса (например, триггер). Либо case_changes - это представление.

Решение - найти объект, созданный от имени удалённого пользователя, и пересоздать его от имени пользователя существующего.

Comment: И как мне найти ? и как пересоздать ?

Comment: спасибо trigger виноват

Comment: то что нужно. спасибо за совет.